# Reading a csv file getting a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, csv, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault, and I have no clue as to why I getting that. It does read in my csv with no problem but at the end of running it I get a segmentation fault. I have tried using the debug feature of Codeblocks and it has not been much help. Could someone point out my error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



void loadCSV(int G[][24]) {
    ifstream csv;
    string line;
    csv.open("matrix.csv");
    if (csv.is_open()){
        int lineNum = 0;
        while ( (getline (csv,line)) && (lineNum!=24)){
            for (int pos = 0;pos<line.length();pos++){
                if (line.at(pos) == ','){
                    continue;
                }
                //cout << line.at(pos);
                if (line.at(pos) == '0'){
                    G[lineNum][pos] = 0;
                    cout << lineNum << "-" << pos << "\n";
                }

                else{
                    G[lineNum][pos] = 1;
                    cout << lineNum << "-" << pos << "\n";;
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
            lineNum++;
        }
        cout << lineNum<< endl;
        csv.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

}



int main(){
    int G[24][24];
    loadCSV(G);
    cout << G[0][1];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the value of  'pos' and 'lineNum' before assigning value  to  G[lineNum][pos]. If any of them is greater/equal than 24, then it's invalid to do the assignment.